# Paying High Bounty in Skyrim PS3

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was recently caught transforming into a werewolf outside of Solitude. I ran off and waited for a while, but now when I try to pay my bounty, the guards just say "Wait...I know you." on a loop every time I try to talk to them.

I have tried sheathing and unsheathing my weapons in front of them repeatedly, but to no avail. I already have enough gold to pay the bounty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the guards having their dialogue on a loop? Do you get the prompt to answer?

Comment: I do not get any prompt to respond.

Comment: Are you on a pc? If so there is an easy fix with console commands.

Comment: Probably should add the PC command for people looking for this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This exact thing happened to me when playing Skyrim on the 360 and it was very annoying because merely walking close to a guard would invoke it.  That was quite some time ago, and I have not seen it happen on the XBox One, so it might have been fixed (by an official or unofficial patch).  Point is, this may never come up again.

That said, I did figure out the solution to this problem:  Punch a guard.

He will immediately start an arrest, and invoke the appropriate dialog options to allow you to clear your bounty in whichever way you prefer.  It does cost a bit extra, but, it was worth it to get rid of the annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

I know on PC there is a command interface that you can pay your bounty through, but I don't know if PS3 has that feature. I would try doing something wrong (steal some stuff or hit someone) and see if that triggers them to try to arrest you.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the guards will continue asking this the whole time you play. I have been told " I know you" even when I did pay off my bounty or got out of jail. what you can try is to enter dialogue with them and once they say they know you, just hit the selection for "I think you're mistaken" or something like that and then they will say that you are a wanted criminal and either take you to jail or let you pay your fine. I play on ps3 as well and I found that even after doing all that they still say it.

Answer (score -3):

The guards don't exactly play a very big role in skyrim and talking to them is pretty useless unless you want side quests. You don't have to worry about this much. If you really want to pay off your bounty, I suggest stealing something small in front of the guards, causing them to attempt to arrest you. To exit the "Wait, I know you" speech, simply press B and exit the convo, this shouldn't be a very big deal unless it's a serious bug that doesn't let the guards arrest or make you pay your bounty. If that is the scenario, I suggest reloading an old save or restarting the game.